# startup folder path for Current user and local machine

Tags: vb.net

How do i get the startup folder path for "Current user" and "All user" in VB.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")  'All Users Directory'
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)) 'Current User Directory'
```

With the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration you also have available a Startup and a CommonStartup enumeration. They map to the current user and the all users startup directory.

Comment: How to i get to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" in my program.

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup) This will give you the path you want

Comment: i found out that Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup) is only can be use in .net 4, is there a way to get the path  "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" for .net 3.5 or lower? thanks.

Comment: From what I can see there is not an easy way to do it. You could build the path by using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")&"\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" this gives the same path in Windows 7 I am not sure on XP

Answer (score 0):

Im unclear about exatly what location you want ill give you a wey to get Environment Variables.

```
Private Function GetEnvironmentVariable(ByVal var As String) As String
    var = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(var)
    Return var
End Function
```

Then pass it the name of the Environment Variable you want.
If you are going to add more to the paths like in Rudu's post, you should keep in mind that paths are different of different operating systems.